# How to disallow LDAP anonymous binding for Windows server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, ldap, anonymous

I have a Windows server 2008 server under domain and security scan found out that LDAP anonymous binding is allowed. So i need to disable the anonymous binding for my domain. I have found a way to do it with Server 2003 using adsiedit.msc, but can't find the same option for server 2008.

Can someone point me right direction for it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows Server 2008, ADSIedit is part of the Active Directory Domain Controller Tools feature:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Quanta for quick response. I found the answer here: http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/active-directory/q-how-do-i-enable-anonymous-ldap-binds-to-windows-server-2008-active-directory-ad-#commentAnchor